# Pass generics class as parameter

Tags: java, generics

In an abstract class, I'd like to pass a generic class as parameter of a function but I really don't know how.

Here it is!

```
public abstract class AbstractConverter<S, T> {

    private Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

    protected T DTOtoEntityConverter(S instance) {
        T destObject = mapper.map(instance, Class<T>);
        return destObject;
    }
}
```

But I can not pass Class as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected T DTOtoEntityConverter(S instance, Class<T> clazz) {
    return mapper.map(instance, clazz);
}
```

You need an instance of the `Class<T>` and you should pass it to the method as well.

If the class has a single method, I would rewrite the method and remove the class generics:

```
public <S, T> T convertDTOToEntityByClass(S DTO, Class<T> clazz) { ... }
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest way to get the Class of T, if not the only.

Comment: `S` is not even needed, as the `mapper` doesn't care what input you're giving him

Answer (score 0):

doing this `mapper.map(instance, Class<T>);`

is like trying to call a method by passing as parameter a type.

like doing `System.out.println(Integer);`

so you need to pass an instance of the class.. that is why you need to do

```
Class<T> foo = //init the class here
mapper.map(instance, foo);
```